# clean mqsitransit directory of file output node in IIB (IBM Integration Bus)

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker

I was working on File Output Node and staging files to mqsitransit directory before finish file. When I pass file name in LocalEnvironment to finish file terminal, the files from mqsitransit directory are moved to output directory.
Now If an exception occurs before I can pass control to finish file terminal, the flow exits. In this case the files are still present in mqsitransit directory, but I don't want those file to be present there. How can I delete those files from mqsitransit directory?

One solution can be by using FileRead Node to read and delete files, but this solution is not good as we have to  specify input directory for this node which will be mqsitransit and as mqsitransit is used by IIB interanlly, we should not specify this path to any node.

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a facility for the FileOutput node to do this itself because doing so would cause data loss.

If you are staging a file you are typically writing individual records to the file, these could have originated from multiple separate transactions so deleting the file would remove the results of these transactions.

If you are operating in whole file mode and you get an exception in those circumstances the file will be deleted.

When you say that the flow exits I am assuming that the flow is rolled back to the input node in which case presumably the input message is available for reprocessing, in which case if you generate an output file with the same file name and set the "Action if file exists" property to either replace the old file, or archive it with optional timestamp.

I would not recommend pointing other file nodes at the mqsitransit directories as they will attempt to create locks on the same files and could impact the original flow.

If you need a way to automatically cleanup files that will never be processed succesfully then you will need to raise an RFE for this feature at the following URI:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?PROD_ID=532